# Static class usages inside Servlets

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, model-view-controller

I've seen a few times a code, where inside of the Servlet was the inner class to store the values of parametrs and do all sort of validations and etc. Is it considered a good practice to do it? Seems to me as you're dublication the entity classes sometimes. Should the bussiness logic be separated from serlvet?
An example of such usage:

```
 private static class RequestShiftPreferences {

    private final String numbOfWorkingHoursPerWeek;
    private final String numbOfDaysOFf;
    private final String workTimePreference;

    private RequestShiftPreferences(String numbOfWorkingHoursPerWeek, String numbOfDaysOFf, String workTimePreference) {
        this.numbOfWorkingHoursPerWeek = numbOfWorkingHoursPerWeek;
        this.numbOfDaysOFf = numbOfDaysOFf;
        this.workTimePreference = workTimePreference;
    }

    public static ShiftPreferencesController.RequestShiftPreferences fromRequestParameters(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return new ShiftPreferencesController.RequestShiftPreferences(
                request.getParameter("numbOfWorkingHoursPerWeek"),
                request.getParameter("numbOfDaysOFf"),
                request.getParameter("workTimePreference"));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main aim of a servlet is **to parse an HTTP request to typed parameters** and **serializing business entity objects to a HTTP result**. (Secondarily, it also might do either directly or indirectly some perimetral tasks like data compressing/decompressing, security, logging, etc.)

Upon this basis, I see no good reason to include inner bean-like classes into a servlet to store the input parameters, because they certainly duplicate the entity beans. And,  being private, those inner objects will be needed to be transformed to entity beans.

Answer (score 0):

The usage demonstrated is used to create a java object that holds all the values of the request. So it is in a way a model if the request. Not business logic.

If the code in the static class is not duplicated and it will only be used in the servlet then the private static class is a good way to encapsulate and hide from other classes.
If you use this style of writing consistently it will be easy to read also.

Basically adding a private static class to a servlet has all the advantages and disadvantages of having private static class in any other class.